# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable using rungekutte

Tags: python, module, ode, callable, runge-kutta

i have a homework and I used my code here to solve symmetrical equation using Runge-Kutta method

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D
#input data
b=0.0529
cd=0.0        
cl=0.0     
cs=0.0
g=9.8
#persamaan diferensial biasa
def F(x,y):
  F=np.zeros(6)
  v=np.sqrt(y[0]**2+y[1]**2+y[2]**2)
  v0=np.sqrt(y[0]**2+y[1]**2)
  F[0]=-b*v*((cd*y[0])+((cl*y[0]*y[2]+cs*v*y[1])/v0))
  F[1]=-b*v*((cd*y[1])+((cl*y[1]*y[2]+cs*v*y[0])/v0))
  F[2]=b*v*(-cd*y[2]+cl*v0)-g
  F[3]=y[0]
  F[4]=y[1]
  F[5]=y[2]
  return F
x = 0.0 #mulai menghitung
xStop = 2.0 #selesai menghitung
y= np.array([10.0,10.0,10.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]) #kondisi awal{y}
h=0.01 #step size
freq = 20
#solusi numerik menggunakan Runge-Kutta orde4
X,Y = integrate(F,x,y,xStop,h)
```

but it ends up like this

```
---> 29 X,Y = integrate(F,x,y,xStop,h)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code imports the sub-module `integrate` from `scipy`. It is a program module, not a callable function, thus the error message.

This module also does not contain an implementation of the fixed-step RK4 algorithm, this you have to take from somewhere else. Also, give it a more specific name like `RK4_integrate`.